# PHP - if row has a specific value, it opens the hyperlink

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have this test.php where it has a a row "notef" with answers "y" or "n"

That "y" or "n" is hyperlinked to another php file "notes2" which it opens good.

now if I wanted the hyperlink only for "y" in that row "notef" how do I do that?

right now it is:

```
$dg -> set_col_dynalink("notef", "notes2.php", array("ord_number"), "", "_new");
```

SHould i use like? Thank you!

```
if ($row['notef']="Y") {
  $dg -> set_col_dynalink("notef", "notes2.php", array("ord_number"), "", "_new");
}
```

Comment: Should probably be `if ($row['notef'] == "Y")` -- note the `==` which is comparison operator instead of `=` which assigns the value.

Comment: that did not work...sorry..